# Create ExtJs extend class

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I try to extend Button like in sencha [example](http://www.slideshare.net/senchainc/creating-ext-js-extensions-and-components).
I do [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kliver/fTYsV/)
And get error: `TypeError: this.addEvents is not a function : 'statesave'`.
Whats wrong?

Comment: The link to the fiddle is not working

Comment: Remember to call the overwritten methods... `this.callParent(arguments)`

Comment: @NULL: Not sure that understand you. Can you give a example?

Comment: @NULL This is about ExtJS 3 so there is no `callParent`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just forgot to call `new` and you had a typo see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fTYsV/2/)

```
PuffButton = Ext.extend(Ext.Button,{
    constructor: function(config){
        PuffButton.superclass.constructor.apply(this,arguments);
        console.log("111111");
        this.on('click',function(){this.el.puff();},this);
    }
});
var puff = new PuffButton({text: 'Puff', renderTo:Ext.getBody()});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use define instead. Extend method is deprecated.

```
  Ext.define('Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```